# Visualizer for Cosmos DB Graph

Tags: graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb, graph-visualization

Does anyone know of a tool to visualize a graph created in Cosmos DB Graph?

I'm looking for something like Gephi (https://gephi.org/), or the tool that OrientDB or Neo4j use.

I'm looking for something that will "connect" to the database. Gephi appears to require an export, and then it uses the exported file. The tools for OrientDB & Neo4j will connect to the server instance and provide graphical results of queries.

BTW, I'm working with the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator at the moment. So I need something that will work on a local development website (localhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a pretty decent web app for graph visualizations available in the Azure Portal. Inside your Cosmos account just click the QuickStart button and then select the Guided Gremlin Tour:
[image]

Create the SalesGraph (you can point the app at any of your graph enabled collections later) and then download the package and run the solution file. You might have to modify the connection strings in appsettings depending on which graph you want to talk to.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that when I migrate to the Azure. Right now, I'm using the Emulator for working locally. I'll update my original post to reflect that.

Comment: I think it would still work with the emulator. You just need to point it using the correct connection settings

Comment: This web app and some other Graph DB tools is also available in Azure-Samples on Githubl: 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-dotnet-graphexplorer

Comment: In this Azure tool it is hard even to display all edges & vertices. It is nothing like Gephi. Queries are hard to figure out & are specific to Cosmos (they do not support all commands from Gremlin). So far choosing Cosmos DB is a big dissapointment.

Answer (score 3):

Download Cosmos DB extension for vscode.

It works well with gremlin API (with some known issue), check below link

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cosmosdb

[image: screen shot of graph visualisation via vscode's cosmos db plugin]

Comment: It appears that the Graph visualization is no longer supported in the Cosmos DB extension and will soon be removed. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cosmosdb/issues/1967

Comment: This is very frustrating, why isn't there a built-in functionality in Cosmos DB Emulator itself... Paid solutions like gdotv are just too expensive, 50 bucks per month for one person, give me a break.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition, the Microsoft docs has a page dedicated to visualization tools:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/visualization-partners

It currently lists:

- [Linkurious Enterprise](https://linkurio.us/product/)
- [Cambridge Intelligence](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/products/)
- [Tom Sawyer Perspectives](https://www.tomsawyer.com/perspectives/)
- [Graphistry](https://www.graphistry.com/)
- [Graphlytic](https://graphlytic.biz/)
- [yWorks](https://www.yworks.com/pages/visualizing-a-microsoft-azure-cosmos-db)

Note:

- I can't recommend any, as I've not used them yet. I've only just started using Cosmos DB.
- These all seem like paid solutions, rather than open-source tools.

## Edit

I've found some alternatives that **might work**:

- Open-source

  - https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb
  - https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp
  - https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer
- https://gdotv.com/

  - Azure Cosmos DB support is behind a monthly pay wall